# How to avoid exceeding TeX capacity when using multi-page tables?

Tags: tables, errors, longtable

I'm using the [`longtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package (together with [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) for alternating row colors and [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for elegant table headers) to generate a huge table. And by huge, I mean it has more than 900 lines and takes up more than 29 pages. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
```

My code is similar to this one:

```
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{54mm}}
% Plus a few other new column types

% Alternating colors starting on 3rd row
\definecolor{tabular-odd-color}{gray}{0.90}
\definecolor{tabular-even-color}{gray}{0.97}
\rowcolors{3}{tabular-odd-color}{tabular-even-color}

\begin{longtable}{DTCNAHHHHHH}

\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 & col5 & col6 & col7 & col8 & col9 & col10 & col11 \\
\midrule
\endhead

% LOTS of rows here. I mean, maybe a few thousand, taking up 30, 40 or more pages.

\bottomrule

\end{longtable}
```

How can I avoid exceeding the TeX capacity?

(I've already read [this page](http://programming.itags.org/tex/131103/), but my rows already have blank lines between them, thus that solution does not apply to me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use luatex it dynamically allocates memory so you are limited by the physical memory available AFAIK (there is no sample file that I can test to tell if it actually works).

Comment: And... how to use LuaTeX? I've never used it, and I have no idea about how it can be used.

Comment: If you are lucky enough, just running `lualatex` on your document would be all what you need if you are not interested in any of the extra goodies LuaTeX provides.

Comment: On my Gentoo system, `texlive-luatex` is not stable yet, and on my Ubuntu server, there is no `lualatex` executable. I guess I'll wait some more months/years until giving lualatex another try.

Comment: Use TeXLive 2010 from TUG, it would take years before it gets into Ubuntu (and will be severely outdated by then). Dunno about Gentoo, by the time I was using it there packaging had became a mess.

Comment: About one year later, I tried `lualatex`. It took about 1.5GB of RAM to compile a huge 827-page longtable, but it worked! (after messing a bit with the preamble because of incompatibilities with lualatex, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex )

Answer (score 1):

A first possibility is to add the option `--extra-mem-top=n` to your invocation of `pdflatex`. Replace `n` by a number of which you suppose it's big enough.

A more permanent solution is to invoke `initexmf --edit-config-file=latex` and change the line with `main_memory`. Afterwards you have to rebuild your format files using `initexmf --dump=latex`. Perform the same for `pdflatex` to get all configurations straight.

But these are just workarounds, there could be other problems with your document that lead to exceeded capacity errors. Does your document compile with a subset of the rows? Are you sure all your `\newcolumntype`'s and such are correct?

Comment: Yeah, it compiles when the number of rows is less than 900. I'm not very sure if my columns are correct, but as I said, they DO work when the number of rows is less than 900.

Comment: Unfortunately, `--extra-mem-top` and `--extra-mem-bot` are parameters exclusive for MiKTeX, and I'm using texlive. :-(

Comment: you can set the `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot` in `texmf.cnf`.

Comment: Your solution is valid, but I'd love to have a solution that would not involve root access, or that at least would not require any extra step configuring the installed packages. Why? Because I don't want things stop working whenever someone updates the system or goes to another machine.