# No room for a new \dimen despite of loading etex

Tags: soul, e-tex

After upgrading to TeX Live 2013 one of my books does not compile any longer. I do load `etex`, but still have not enough room. What can I do? Back in 1994 I had a colleague who hacked the LaTeX source code and increased the number of registers there, but this is probably not the way to go. Is there anything I can do? Loading `eetex` or even `eeetex`? =:-) I can compile the document when I do not load `soul`, but I need `\st`.

Edit: This is the error message

```
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.322 \newinsert\@indexbox

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 22107 strings out of 493316
 370083 string characters out of 6137929
 515169 words of memory out of 5000000
 25110 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 10432 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,1n,77p,581b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

This is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etex}


\usepackage{ifthen}
\provideboolean{draft}
\setboolean{draft}{false}

\usepackage[latin1,utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{jambox}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=126mm,textheight=196mm,tmargin=25mm,driver=dvips]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{ngerman}\selectlanguage{german}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}


\newdimen\widelabel
\widelabel=0.0pt


\usepackage{tree-dvips,pstricks,pst-node,lastpage,float,comment,soul}


\usepackage{ogonek} 


\usepackage{authorindex}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,hyperindex=true,%
breaklinks=true,
draft=false,plainpages=false,hyperfootnotes=false,%
pdfauthor={Stefan Müller},%
pdftitle={Grammatiktheorie},%
pdfkeywords={PSG, GB, GPSG, HPSG, LFG, TAG, LTAG, Syntax, Deutsch},
ps2pdf=true  %ohne diesen Treiber geht der Zeilenumbruch in URLs
]{hyperref}% for pdf files

\usepackage{breakurl}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{varioref,ifthen}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{index}

\begin{document}

Unfortunately there was no room left for the book.

\end{document}
```

I think it is this one call to \newdim, which I extracted from a non-CTAN stylefile that I use, that makes the difference ...

Comment: Please, what does the `Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:` at the end of the `.log` file show? And would the question [Increase LaTeX capacity](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/increase-latex-capacity) be of any use for you?

Comment: Usually this is a problem with inserts: could we have a short example to try things out?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen and answers to it, particularly `\reserveinserts`.

Comment: OK. Thanks. This worked. I read this, but thought it does not apply, since I did not load the packages that were mentioned.

Comment: You appear to be using latex rather than pdflatex? also your example program loads loads of packages (most of which we don't have) so it's hard to help. etex offers  \reserveinserts{17} to reserve 17 more insert classes but I got lots of errors from your example program but not the one you show

Comment: oh @egreg just beat me to it:-(