# Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Tags: packages, pdftex, luatex

I'm in the process of switching my LaTeX document from `pdflatex` to `lualatex`. Similar to [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/) I would like to know, what are typical packages loaded with LuaLaTeX and which typical pdfLaTeX packages should be removed or replaced?

The following are the main difference I found so far:

- Don't use `inputenc`, but instead save your plain files in utf-8 and add the following as the first line: `% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"`.
- Don't use font-packages but instead load `fontspec` with `\setmainfont{FONT_NAME}`, `\setsansfont{FONT_NAME}`, `\setmonofont{FONT_NAME}`.
- In order to make `microtype` work with `fontspec`, use the beta version of `microtype` (At least with TeX Live 2011). [See more details](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/111).
- `hyperref` should be loaded with the option `unicode`.

What other packages do you use? What about `babel` and `textcomp`? And are there some "killer-packages" that are only working with `lualatex` besides `fontspec`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Besides supporting a Lua interpreter, LuaTeX brings to pdfTeX quite the same changes as XeLaTeX (native Unicode support, support for system fonts).

For this reason, [the question you linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/) applies to LuaTeX as well, modulo the answers to [this question about migrating from XeTeX to LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/considerations-when-migrating-from-xetex-to-luatex), which shows that apart from [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) support and font names, LuaTeX- and XeTeX-specific codes are mostly compatible.

[`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) works fine with LuaTeX as far as I can tell. At least with `frenchb`, I haven't had any issues.

Besides [`fontspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) (which also works with XeTeX), there's more and more packages that use Lua to provide features. As an example, I have recently released the [`impnattypo`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo) package which has some LuaTeX specific features (thanks to [Patrick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/patrick)), and I have more coming (such as the unreleased `overcolored` package).

Comment: Perhaps it's best to load `polyglossia` instead of `babel` with LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 27):

Most usage questions for LuaLaTeX are answered in [`lualatex-doc.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

Similar to the MWE in the [linked XeLaTeX question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/), 
here is a MWE for LuaLaTeX. 
It uses the [`ifluatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifluatex) package to allow switching between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (remember to delete all `.aux` files).
I used the fonts from the [Microsoft ClearType fonts](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypeFonts.mspx), 
because they look good on screen and printed.

```
% !TEX program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    ngerman,
    final
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    % Lua(La)TeX
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    %\usepackage{polyglossia}   
    %\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math} 
    \unimathsetup{math-style=TeX}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Constantia} 
    \setsansfont{Calibri}
    \setmonofont{Consolas}
    \setmathrm{Cambria Math}
    \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\else
    %default: pdf(La)TeX
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{lmodern} % load vector font
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\fi

\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}


%% ==================
\begin{document}
\chapter{Goldener Schnitt}
Beim Goldenen Schnitt (lateinisch: sectio aurea) oder auch bei der Goldenen Teilung 
--- seltener beim Göttlichen Schnitt oder bei der Göttlichen Teilung (lateinisch: proportio divina) --- 
entsteht ein bestimmtes Verhältnis zwischen zwei Zahlen oder zwei Größen.
Dieses Verhältnis ist die Goldene Zahl $\Phi$ (Phi) (oder das Goldene Verhältnis oder das Göttliche Verhältnis) und hat den Wert
\begin{equation}
    \Phi=\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1{,}618
\end{equation}
Zum Beispiel stehen zwei Teile einer Strecke im Verhältnis $\Phi$, 
wenn sich der größere zum kleineren Teil verhält wie die ganze Strecke zum größeren Teil.
\begin{equation}
    \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a+b}{a}
\end{equation}
Streckenverhältnisse wie beim Goldenen Schnitt werden seit der griechischen Antike als Inbegriff von Ästhetik und Harmonie angesehen. 
Sie werden als ideale Proportionen in Kunst und Architektur angewendet, 
kommen aber auch in der Natur vor. 
Das Goldene Verhältnis ist häufig bei der Bildkomposition in der Malerei zu finden und wird heute oft in der Photographie verwendet. 
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{10}{p{7mm}@{}}}
    Some T1 characters:     & \# & \$ & \% & Ă & Ň & § & @ & Æ & ß   & £   \\[1.5mm]
    Some non-T1 characters: & ‡  & ÿ  & ‰  & … & ¶ & ½ & ĩ & µ & | | & | | \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Es zeichnet sich durch eine Reihe besonderer mathematischer Eigenschaften aus.
Umgangssprachlich wird Goldener Schnitt auch für die Goldene Zahl beziehungsweise für das Goldene Verhältnis gebraucht.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest to not use the ClearType fonts as a default as they are—as far as I know—only provided in Windows. Hence using the TeX Gyre fonts or the Libertine might be a better solution for the MWE as they come bundled with TeX Live (and I think MikTeX too) and therefore are available on most TeX installations.

Comment: You can also install these fonts on Linux: http://venutip.com/content/installing-vista-fonts-ubuntu and they seem to be very complete, also they match nicely together. Also, I frequently include pdf graphics generated with Excel, so I definetly want to use a font that is available system wide. If you have a better suggestion, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that one could install them on Linux but reading the guide you linked, it doesn't seem to be a thing one wants to do to just make a MWE running.  My point is to use a font in the MWE that comes with TeX Live or MikTeX, such as TeX Gyre or Libertine. Using them you won't need to install anything more but your TeX distribution to use the MWE.

Comment: Yes, MWEs should work without further effort, especially without something like installing fonts from another OS.