# Use downloaded font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I have downloaded some original fonts from Adobe (Helvetica, Times and others), they are all otf, I installed them on Windows and I can use them with no problem with Indesign and other softwares. However I am now trying to use them in LaTeX (I am a beginner) with no success.

In particular I load the package helvet for example, but it is used a font that resembles helvetica, but is not helvetica. Since I have the original one, I'd like to use it.

So, how to make LaTeX recognize and use my otf? Do I have to set them up manually or is there a package that can do it?

Comment: Use xelatex or lualatex and the `fontspec` package, these tex variants use system fonts,

Comment: Another beginner's question: can I use on Lualatex and xelatex the same packages I use on Latex?

Comment: @user2892453 most of the packages should work in those formats also.

Comment: @user2892453 mostly, but don't use inputenc

Comment: As for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex.